# error when not getting body when using http's put method

Tags: node.js, http, put

I'm currently creating a project that uses a socket to send http requests to the web server, but I'm having problems with the put method. According to my understanding, the content format when sending to the mail server will be:`POST /path HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1\r\n\r\nbodytext`,
[and here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKi7b.png), [This is when the server receives it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoQjh.png)the content is essentially the same, although it lacks many other options. But when I send it to the server, the server doesn't receive the body part. Why is that? I hope to receive your help. I'm a newbie so I hope to receive your support. Thank you.

I tried re-reading the slides and I couldn't seem to find my mistakes